# Installing PNGwriter library in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, freetype

I'm trying to setup pngwriter library in codeblocks for c++. I've used this tutorial (http://www.neuron-hub.com/2011/06/setting-up-pngwriter-with-code.html) but something isn't working. I'm almost a beginner at c++, and those library installs are killing me.

When I build it like it says in tutorial, in codeblocks opens another tab called ft2build.h and says

```
#ifndef __FT2_BUILD_UNIX_H__
#define __FT2_BUILD_UNIX_H__

/* `<prefix>/include/freetype2' must be in your current inclusion path */
#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>

#endif /* __FT2_BUILD_UNIX_H__ */

/* END */
```

so the question is does anybody know what the problem is here? Tutorial is simple and I repeated it at least 20 times and the result is the same.

Comment: Does it report errors on the `#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>` line?

Comment: So how did you build the freetype library? (did you ever built it)?

Comment: I used installer for freetype library, downloaded as instructed on tutorial page.

Comment: Do you maybe know what's the problem?

Comment: Verify that you have `/usr/include/freetype` and `/usr/lib/libft2.so` or similar on your system. If not, you haven't built and installed correctly. Provide a url to the instructions page you say so we know what did you do.

Comment: http://www.neuron-hub.com/2011/06/setting-up-pngwriter-with-code.html  is url for tutorial so please check it

Comment: in mingw folder i have freetype installed, so i dont know whats the problem, and why wont it work, if you have any more suggestions, please help - tnx

Answer (score -1):

You must include `..\include\freetype2\` into the path where Codeblocks searches for necessary headers.